# Google cloud transfer from HTTPs server : URL of TSV?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Sorry for my noob question :(

I'm trying to transfer data from a HTTPS server to my google bucket using google cloud transfer service. I've created the tsv file according to the documentation. But I'm not sure how to give the link of the tsv file to google cloud transfer service. Do I need to upload that tsv in someplace like google drive and get a link and then put it in the URL of TSV box? If not what is the procedure. Please enlighten me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just provide a public URL that refers to the tsv. AS stated in [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/create-manage-transfer-console#configure),

> Under URL of TSV file, **provide the URL to a tab-separated values (TSV) file**, then click Continue. See Creating a URL List for details about how to create the TSV file.

You can use the link obtained by Drive or just upload the file to Google Cloud Storage and share it in public.